# User defined validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I would like to kwnow if it possible for users to add validation rules at runtime. I have a system that will be sold to clients that could be anywhere in the world. So in some countries certain fields is required and in other those fields are not required. So i thought I would add functionality so that when i implement the system, the fields that needs to be validated could be set by me, without the need to add the data-annotations to the properties, then recompile the entire system.

It will be an ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework

regards

Comment: try fluentvalidation http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks Yorgo. How do i mark what you said as the answer

Comment: i add answer you can mark that. thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try fluentvalidation http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following way

1. Use data-annotations with the properties
2. And while using the annotation check on your view there you can check which country it is by using a simple if else condition, and show the checks only at the required country views

   ```
   if(someCondition)
   {
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.User.Username)
   }
   ```