# EF Model Validation Values from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I wonder how could I make Model validation from database.
for example

I have a class called `User`

It has property `public string UserName {get; set;}`

This property has Data annotation attribute `[StringLength(100)]`

And I want change those values dynamical I mean 100. I want make admin panel where admin can for example change those values from 100 to wantever he wants for example 20. This is only a example.

How could I do this ?

I have idea to make new classes for every attribute for example
`StringLenght` that inherits from `ValidationAttribute`

```
MyOwnclass : StringLength
```

So `StringLength` inherits from `ValidationAttribute`

In this class I could make `DBContext` and read those values in overridden `IsValid` Method. But I don't know how long would it take. For example I have a Register view with 15 form inputs. Every input would make at least 1 request to database. Performance could be bad ?

Ss there any other way to do this maybe store those values in application memory ? And update it in Admin Controller when he changes this setting ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975535/user-defined-validation.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, you can store the length in separate table, and change it from admin panel. 
Every time you insert/update user, check this variable first. You can use stored procedure or override [ValidateEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.validateentity%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) function to validate UserName of  new/updated user.

Comment: yes but i want client side valiadion also and i dont think it would work like this.